# Include javascript file as inline javascript in Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

Is there a way to include a js file in javascript in my view?

```
$js =<<< JS
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("beforeInsert", function(e, item) {
    echo $this->registerJsFile('@web/js/yii2-dynamic-form_mod.js', ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_BEGIN]);   
    });  

  JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yii2 registering JS files to a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656777/yii2-registering-js-files-to-a-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use for example:

```
$this->registerJsFile("js/jquery-ui.min.js", ['depends' => 'yii\web\JqueryAsset']);
```

Further info:
[Class yii\web\View](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-view#registerJsFile()-detail)

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this `<?= Html::jsFile('@web/js/main.js') ?>` Read more in [Yii doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html#styles-and-scripts)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get file content:

```
$jsFileContent = file_get_contents(Yii:getAlias('@web/js/yii2-dynamic-form_mod.js'));
$js = <<<JS
    $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("beforeInsert", function(e, item) {
        $jsFileContent
    }
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```